# Let's get critical: Jan 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is it possible to learn Martial Arts (Kung Fu in my case) effectively without sparring?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4605/is-it-possible-to-learn-martial-arts-kung-fu-in-my-case-effectively-without-sp)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to deal with unfair judges](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/how-to-deal-with-unfair-judges)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the name of this style of Karate (maybe?)?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/what-is-the-name-of-this-style-of-karate-maybe)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are the advantage of wearing a rashguard under the Gi in BJJ?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/what-are-the-advantage-of-wearing-a-rashguard-under-the-gi-in-bjj)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In MMA, should you try to block punches with your glove in the same way you could in Muay Thai?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/in-mma-should-you-try-to-block-punches-with-your-glove-in-the-same-way-you-coul)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the name of this Taekwondo black belt bo form?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4596/what-is-the-name-of-this-taekwondo-black-belt-bo-form)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can my body learn to split at 25?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/can-my-body-learn-to-split-at-25)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Please tell me the correct way to sit seiza](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4586/please-tell-me-the-correct-way-to-sit-seiza)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Chinese Dadao info?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/chinese-dadao-info)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Does judo work against someone not wearing a judogi?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4653/does-judo-come-to-the-power-without-judoga)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---